# Choice of penalty parameter for lasso with logit link function?

Tags: cross-validation, lasso, logit

I need to estimate a logistic regression that is penalized by the L1-norm. Choosing the penalty parameter by cross-validation is too computationally expensive for my application. I was wondering whether there was a simple formula I can use? I am aware that simple formulas exist in the linear case but do not know of one when there is a logistic link function.

Any help appreciated.